Interface types missing in class object generation from JSON file
I'm trying to load a JSON file into a Array of class objects. But I receive the following error:
Argument of type '(room: IRoomManager) => RoomManager' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { id: number; name: string; description: string; participants: never[]; capacity: number; status: boolean; }, index: number, array: { id: number; name: string; description: string; participants: never[]; capacity: number; status: boolean; }[]) => RoomManager'.
  Types of parameters 'room' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id: number; name: string; description: string; participants: never[]; capacity: number; status: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IRoomManager': getId, getName, getDescription, getParticipants, and 7 more.

Is this caused because I added the functions from the RoomManager class to the interface or what is causing this issue?
initializeRooms = () => {
  this.rooms = RoomConfig.map(
    (room: IRoomManager) =>
      new RoomManager(
        room.id,
        room.name,
        room.description,
        room.participants,
        room.capacity,
        room.status,
      ),
  );

  logger.gameDebugMessage(`${this.rooms.length} rooms initialized`);
};

which is supposed to load an imported JSON file:
const rooms = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Room 1',
    description: 'Example',
    participants: [],
    capacity: 20,
    status: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Room 2',
    description: 'Example',
    participants: [],
    capacity: 20,
    status: true,
  },
];

export default rooms;

and write all rooms to a array: rooms: RoomManager[]; which is of the type of the RoomManager class:
import IRoomManager from '../interfaces/IRoomManager';
import IClientRoomData from '../interfaces/IClientRoomData';
import PlayerManager from './player.manager';

class RoomManager implements IRoomManager {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  participants: PlayerManager[];
  capacity: number;
  status: boolean;

  constructor(
    id: number,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    participants: PlayerManager[],
    capacity: number,
    status: boolean,
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.participants = participants;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.status = status;
  }

  getId = (): number => this.id;
  getName = (): string => this.name;
  getDescription = (): string => this.description;
  getParticipants = (): PlayerManager[] => this.participants;
  getCapacity = (): number => this.capacity;
  getStatus = (): boolean => this.status;

  setDescription = (description: string) => {
    this.description = description;
  };

  setParticipants = (participants: PlayerManager[]) => {
    this.participants = participants;
  };

  setCapacity = (capacity: number) => {
    this.capacity = capacity;
  };

  setStatus = (status: boolean) => {
    this.status = status;
  };

  generateRoomList = (): IClientRoomData => {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      description: this.description,
      participant_count: this.participants.length,
      capacity: this.capacity,
      status: this.status,
    };
  };
}

export default RoomManager;

The implemented interface looks like the following:
import PlayerManager from './IPlayerManager';
import IClientRoomData from './IClientRoomData';

interface IRoomManager {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  participants: PlayerManager[];
  capacity: number;
  status: boolean;
  getId: () => number;
  getName: () => string;
  getDescription: () => string;
  getParticipants: () => PlayerManager[];
  getCapacity: () => number;
  getStatus: () => boolean;
  setDescription: (description: string) => void;
  setParticipants: (participants: PlayerManager[]) => void;
  setCapacity: (capacity: number) => void;
  setStatus: (status: boolean) => void;
  generateRoomList: () => IClientRoomData;
}

export default IRoomManager;


Yes,  any object compatible with IRoomManagerwould require all corresponding functions to also be available. You can say something likeinterrace IRoomManagerCtorArgs { ... }to define what the JSON objects will look like and theninterface IRoomManager extends IRoomManagerCtorArgsto specify the functions that would be available. Though personally I would prefer the interface to not dictate what functions need to be implemented and just useRoomManager` to indicate that functions are available to that specific instance
